# How can I dynamically switch between CSS files served from node_modules?

Tags: css, vue.js, npm, import

I currently have an NPM package that exports two files:

`Theme-One.css` and `Theme-Two.css`

Each file is formatted in the exact same manner, a root styling object containing CSS variables:

`:root { --primary-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) --secondary-color: rgb(0, 0, 0) }`

Then in the consuming repo, the color variables will be used in CSS files to allow for switching between themes and keep components adhering to the color scheme.

How can I import them both - but conditionally used the one I'd like based on a variable?

I have tried using a dynamic import that fires on mount, and again whenever the variable to set the theme changes:

```
function loadTheme(themeName) {
  import('@my-npm-package/${themeName}-styles.css')
 }
```

but I'm met with this error: `TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier '@my-npm-package/Theme-One-web-styles.css'`

Neither style takes effect using this method, whereas if I just import one as a normal CSS file at the top level of the file, it works as expected.

Is there a way to dynamically set which one is being used?